# Script doesn't copy template for 1 out of 4 of my templates

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 4 templates that are created based off a spreadsheet values.  getInfo() gets the value array for use in createAttend().  I have createAgenda, createEval and createBooking which are all basically copies of the below.   I have 5 buttons, 1 button for each individual and 1 for create all. which is just:

```
function createAll() {

createEval()
createAttend()
createAgenda()
createReg()
}
```

I've tried using the individual button and the create all button but it doesn't seem to like the attend one only.  I've double checked the ID and it's correct but I can't work out why it's not working.  I thought it could be a value in the array causing an issue but why would that effect only one of the templates?

```
function getInfo() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
var infoRange = sheet.getRange(9,1,1,6)
var infoData = infoRange.getValues()

Logger.log(infoData)
return infoData



}

function createAttend() {
var attendLog = DriveApp.getFileById("1IhfDbR1epbRkAAifJjwuE5zvOcr0LIEP4hvKziN1lwo")

var templateData = getInfo()


var folder = templateData[0][0]
var meetingName = templateData[0][1]
var date = templateData[0][2]
var time = templateData[0][3]
var location = templateData[0][4]
var meetingTitle = templateData [0][5]

var fileName = meetingTitle + " Attendace Log"
var copyTemplate = attendLog.makeCopy()
var copyId = copyTemplate.getId()
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId)
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection()
if (folder != "") {
copyTemplate.setName(fileName)

var meetingFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder)
var meetingForm = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId)

meetingFolder.addFile(meetingForm)
meetingForm.getParents().next().removeFile(meetingForm)

copyBody.replaceText('%Meeting Name%', meetingName)
copyBody.replaceText('%Date%', date)
copyBody.replaceText('%Location%', location)
copyBody.replaceText('%Time%', time)
}
}
```

Edit:
createEval, createAgenda, createAttend are copies of each other in terms of the code with just variables changed.  Both createEval and createAgenda created the drafts from template but createAttend didn't.  I couldn't find anything in the bin as I thought it might be deleted.

Comment: Can you give some more information about the actual error?

Comment: Why are you using an extra function to extract data from the sheet? It adds a layer of complexity that isn't really necessary. Check the Execution transcript (in the _View_ menu) after running the script because it will display any errors encountered while running.

Comment: Hi James and Brian, execution log says it succeeded and no error pops up, just no file appears in the folder.

AS for the extra function, I think that might be a remnant from my first attempts at the script.  I'm self teaching all this at the moment so there's a lot of trial and many more errors.